# Express Routes params to define react page components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes

I am learning `Express.js`, this is my case, i have 2 urls

```
/security/1

/security/2
```

The answer to that request will be the following, depending on the answer, the `"/security/{id}"` will return a Web page that will show and enable a certain number of "elements".

```
app.get('/security/:id', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(
    () =>
      res.send({
        access: req.params.id === '1' ? ['EDIT', 'DELETE', 'VIEW', 'ADD'] : ['VIEW'],
      }),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000 + 100)
  );
});
```

My question is now that i have flagged the elements based on the request parameter, how can i render my react page ( for example `index.js` ) flagging these elements

I would appreciate any example or code answer helping me to figure it out the approach

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your question but you can make request from your frontend React page and based on the result you can render whatever you want.